# How to debug a rule that doesn't want to fire?

Tags: 7, rules, flags, debugging

I have nodes that can be flagged with a global flag.
When a node is updated I want a rule to unflag that node.

- *Rules Event*: After updating existing content
- *Rules Action*: Unflag a node.

  I then select the flag, "data selector" = node, "User on whose behalf to flag" = node:author (this field should be ignored because it's a global flag),
  "permission check" is unchecked.

When I update a node which has a global flag set, it doesn't get removed.

Did I set it up wrong? How can I debug a rule that doesn't want to fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Flag Module**

"User on whose behalf to flag" will not be ignored in this case.

When a flag is global, users don't necessarily have the required permission to toggle it.  Be sure that the user role is allowed to flag or unflag the flag in question.

A nodes 'published' status is a good example of a 'global flag' (though it has nothing to do with the flag module.)  When `published` is TRUE content is visible, when FALSE it's hidden.  Though the flag is global, only those with the 'publish content' permission can toggle it.  The Flag module works similarly.

---

**Rules Module**

Rules has a built-in debugger that is useful at times.  It can be found at admin/config/workflow/rules/settings

---

I generally end up falling back on [dd](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7)() or [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)() though when debugging rules.  Rules is an incredible module for sure, but debugging at times can be a pain.

Comment: interesting. Yeah, the user changing the node doesn't have permission to flag/unflag since it's an admin flag. I guess I could add the permission and just don't  display the flag links for regular users.

Comment: wow, looks like there was a bug in flag rules, the "permission check" box is really a "skip permission check" box http://drupal.org/node/1550540. When I enable it everything works fine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is great, but sometimes also tough to debug if things don't work as you'd expect. There are some typical facilities to do such debugging (further detailed below), but a **K**eep-**I**t-**S**uper-**S**imple technique I often use, is my ***BINGO***-trick. A sample of such rule can be found in my answer to "[Which Rules condition can be used to email a user when an admin updates their profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180576/which-rules-condition-can-be-used-to-email-a-user-when-an-admin-updates-their-pr/180587#180587)". Stupid, but simple and efficient (I think).

If the above doesn't help, then there are typically 2 ways of more advanced debugging, as further detailed below.

## Rules Evaluation Log

Within the Rules **settings**, experiment a bit with the debugging facilities that come with the rules module. At least have a look at the "***Rules Evaluation Log***" (to check that the Rules logic being executed, actually matches what you expect that logic to be).

## Rules Action to display a value (using devel)

You may also want to (temporary) enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, so that you can (temporary) add a Rules Action like "Display a value".

Obviously, make sure that there are no Rules Conditions that would prevent the rules Action(s) from being executed (if needed temporary remove such Rules Conditions).

## More info

For way more details about these 2 variations, refer to **Rules debugging**, as explained in the answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".