# Why does the php evaluation not work in my rules condition?

Tags: 7, rules

I am trying to add the condition inside a commerce notification: *"Order has one or more products where the sku contains."*. What I basically need is *"Order has only products where the sku contains"*.

The string that must be contained in the SKU is `FOOBAR_`.

The operator is `=`.

The amount: `<?php print count($commerce_order->commerce_line_items); ?>`

So the condition should just be true when all of the order's line items' products contain `FOOBAR_` in their SKUs. But the php replacement does not seem to work. In the tooltip under `PHP EVALUATION` it says:

> PHP code inside of `<?php ?>` delimiters will be evaluated and replaced
>   by its output. E.g. `<?php echo 1+1?>` will be replaced by 2. Furthermore
>   you can make use of the following variables: $commerce_order

When I put in a hardcoded amount it works, but then its not dynamic, obviously.

[image]

Comment: print count($commerce_order->commerce_line_items); return a number and you want  compare it with string ?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Rules debugging, similar to what is described [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44353/how-to-debug-a-rule-that-doesnt-want-to-fire/199574#199574)