# Rules not firing at user creation for non default language

Tags: users, 6, rules

I created a rule that delete a user when a profile field contains a particular, troll specific pattern. It works perfectly when registering with the default language (fr) as current.

[image]

When registering in the alternate site language (en) as current, the rule does not fire at all, even when removing all conditions, trying different actions.

Other non-rules modules perfectly handle that event (for user registration notification for example), but Rules silently fails.

Other events are normally handled whatever is the current language

I tried to disable all path related modules without change

Any idea where I shall look at?

Many thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: An export OR a screen shot of your rule would go a long way. Also, please specify your Drupal version.

Comment: I am on D6, there are no export feature for rules. It is a very simple one, triggered by "User account has been created". Screenshot here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnMOq4Xa5UTnbRrmzgzE1ac88eA

Comment: The fact that D6 is "unsupported" seems to make this community uniterrested to consider that type of question. I found Drupal a great platform until I realized that it was driven by a community of geeks who has no respect for laggards who do not appreciate their brand new version that is 100% incompatible with the old one.

Comment: On your screenshot your rule has no action. For testing purposes, add action of show message on the site. It might be possible that your theme does not show messages, so I would suggest using the default Drupal theme for this test just in case.

Comment: The rule has an action : Do "Supprimer l'utilisateur" (= "Delete user") - This rule works perfectly in French - is silent in English

Comment: Sorry I missed that, D6 was before my time, not used to the D6 Rules UI.
Create a new rule from scratch and use show message on the site for action, don't put anything for the IF (condition) and see what happens.

Comment: I did that, as explain in the case, I defined a new rule with a single action sending a message without any condition -  ok in French, nothing happens in English

Comment: well, that's odd, should've worked. You could try dbuging it with [these suggestions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199574/27710)

Comment: New hints: only "create user" event rule from anonymous (not when creating by admin) fails.